# Directory.GetFiles() doesnt understand packs?

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to get an array of images out of my folder with this:

```
var files = 
Directory.GetFiles("pack://application:,,,/Recources/Weapons", 
"*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But for some reason this fails because the paths format is not supported? doesnt this pack work?
It works with the Full path

```
var files = 
Directory.GetFiles
("C:/Users/luis-/source/repos/BF4 Random Weapon/BF4 Random Weapon/Recources/Weapons");
```

Comment: You should be fine with *.png if you have a normal conventional folder to look in

Comment: The `Directory` class works with the actual filesystem and doesn't know about WPF.

Comment: Did you spelt resources wrong?

Comment: approach with files is fragile. instead of working with image files, add them as actual resources and retrive from `Resources` class (which should be located in project Properties node in visual studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pack URIs are a WPF specific thing that the `Directory.GetFiles` method knows nothing about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf.

You will need to provide a physical path to a real folder on disk where the files actually exist. Passing a pack URI to the `Directory.GetFiles` method is not supported and won't work.

Comment: is there some other way to get all files in a resource folder then?